# What's the deal with custom ASP.NET MembershipProviders?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I'm hoping someone can help me wrap my head around what's going on when I try to implement a custom MembershipProvider.  This is probably more of a theory question than a code question...here's what I have:

- MVC 2 app (started from an empty MVC 2 project)
- SQL Server DB with my own "users" table
- A User class, UserRepository, UserService, blah blah blah

Currently, my application authenticates via the UserRepository which returns a User object if successful.  This User object is then stored in the session and is subsequently interrogated by all controller actions that require authentication.

Now...I understand that storing this in the session leaves me vulnerable to session hijacking and that a more secure method would be to implement my own MembershipProvider.  What I don't understand is, where would this custom Provider end up storing my User object?  I see that the overridden ValidateUser() method  just returns a bool, but I can't figure out where that information is persisted for that user's time on the site.

I'd really like to keep my existing process while making it more secure by taking away the dependence on session for user authentication.  I like having a complete user object at my disposal throughout the application once the user is logged in, but I'm open to suggestions otherwise.  It seems that a lot of the MembershipProvider documentation is kinda black-box.  I'm hoping that someone can explain what it's actually doing under the hood to persist user authentication.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a user is validated ASP.Net Membership creates a token (a large encrypted string) that is stored as a cookie or as part of the URL string depending on how you configure it in the config. It can optionally do either based on whether cookies are available or not. The token is used to persist the identity of the user to answer your main question about how it works at low levels. Everything else associated (roles, profile, etc) is retrieved from the server depending on how the custom provider is implemented.

It's not necessarily true that this is more secure than session - it has the same vulnerabilities of URL or cookie replay if the site is not protected by SSL encryption (worse with URL in case the users email around url's to others).

Comment: Interesting...I hadn't even considered SSL in this little experiment, but I am planning to implement SSL in the near future on this site.  If that's the case, then Session would inherently be protected by SSL as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, it would protect that as well. One of the more vulnerable places for cookie exposure without SSL is unencrypted wireless networks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the way Microsoft did there's they released the source

[Provider Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/Source-Code-for-the-Built_2D00_in-ASP.NET-2.0-Providers-Now-Available-for-Download.aspx)

Also remember nothing is a black box in .Net you can use [Just Decomile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or [reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to learn more about how others(Microsoft) have done the same thing you want to do.

Comment: Very cool, I'll spend some time reading through this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from all the answers, I believe the *missing link* in your post is ASP.Net Forms Authentication - this is actually what **uses** ASP.Net Membership in an ASP.Net web application.

So if you have your own db and auth scheme (already) in place, you can use Forms Authentication with it - even **without** trying to make it work with Membership (you really don't have to).

Here's (quickly becoming my most used link) an [overly simplistic MSDN example of Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) with the scheme hard coded. It shows you that you can even do it that way - not that you should of course, but just shows you the possibilities.

As all the answers above have stated, you can build your own provider if you require. The farthest I've gone (so far) hasn't been to build one, but just customize a few methods. Reason: the existing user db of a project I had was using MD5. This meant I just overrode 2 methods (if memory serves that is) - `ValidateUser()` and `CreateUser()`....

Hth

Comment: This is what I've been looking for...good find!  It seems like it's always so difficult to find examples of the most simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excellent tutorial on implementing your own custom MembershipProvider.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

That being said, you really need to read the article. Once you read the article and follow the steps, you'll start to understand the answer to your questions. There's really not a great way to understand it other than going through the drudgery of following a tutorial like this. At least, that is my opinion. I just implemented my own custom membership provider for the first time by going through this tutorial. After a few hours, I was able to start implementing my own encryption algorithms.

Comment: I actually read through that article earlier today.  It's very informative, but I still don't understand how the user's authentication status is persisted between page views once they're logged in.  For example, I expected to see a call to FormsAuthentication.SetCookie() or something in either the GetUser() method or the ValidateUser() method.  Does that happen automatically in the method that calls GetUser()?

Comment: Yes ASP.Net automatically handles that plumbing using a cookie or URL parameters to retrieve the identity token.

Comment: *Implementing my own encryption algorithms* is a notoriously bad idea.

Comment: For the record, I have a B.S. in Computer Science and studied cryptography. All that I actually did was add a database password salt a SHA512 algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using the standard Membership Provider but creating a link table to join your existing user repository to the asp net membership provider. Best of both worlds.